# How to split byte array into 4 bytes and convert result to float?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, udp, byte

I am currently developing a display application for F1 2017 on my iPhone using swift. I am able to read the UDP packets from my PS4 to my phone by using [SwiftSockets](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket).

I received the following data:

```
[25, 79, 3, 64, 176, 153, 15, 61, 244, 133, 165, 69, 0, 20, 145, 192, 223, 145, 218, 194, 165, 106, 64, 64, 15, 88, 234, 67, 220, 222, 109, 59, 168, 219, 67, 187, 42, 245, 4, 59, 200, 163, 186, 57, 65, 126, 46, 63, 22, 207, 77, 59, 13, 81, 59, 191, 127, 79, 59, 191, 0, 73, 203, 187, 141, 126, 46, 191, 180, 81, 37, 190, 5, 254, 41, 189, 251, 167, 151, 62, 145, 185, 39, 62, 7, 210, 92, 63, 203, 186, 128, 192, 218, 25, 99, 64, 112, 21, 0, 191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 63, 24, 106, 72, 61, 239, 89, 49, 187, 0, 0, 192, 64, 191, 199, 133, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 65, 0, 80, 195, 72, 0, 80, 195, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 63, 75, 253, 209, 66, 0, 0, 210, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 182, 232, 65, 80, 182, 232, 65, 80, 182, 232, 65, 80, 182, 232, 65, 0, 0, 172, 65, 0, 0, 172, 65, 0, 0, 184, 65, 0, 0, 184, 65, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 198, 66, 57, 170, 165, 69, 128, 93, 205, 66, 0, 128, 84, 70, 0, 96, 134, 69, 0, 0, 16, 65, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 252, 68, 240, 253, 176, 66, 131, 119, 113, 188, 93, 249, 95, 187, 28, 146, 43, 59, 116, 163, 23, 188, 87, 87, 88, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 54, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 200, 88, 12, 67, 0, 0, 255, 20, 0, 146, 115, 234, 194, 88, 249, 59, 64, 95, 94, 231, 67, 128, 93, 205, 66, 176, 153, 15, 61, 24, 134, 204, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 192, 122, 64, 100, 2, 18, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 245, 73, 129, 193, 65, 222, 85, 64, 134, 169, 0, 68, 32, 234, 205, 66, 224, 188, 92, 67, 94, 87, 203, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 62, 112, 162, 69, 34, 2, 15, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0, 134, 253, 181, 65, 69, 178, 83, 64, 5, 6, 10, 68, 136, 6, 200, 66, 70, 194, 141, 67, 180, 236, 199, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 208, 160, 69, 16, 0, 5, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0, 16, 137, 185, 195, 194, 6, 44, 64, 211, 20, 153, 66, 64, 15, 198, 66, 238, 232, 27, 61, 64, 15, 198, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 253, 67, 0, 1, 1, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 83, 13, 149, 65, 96, 78, 84, 64, 101, 6, 9, 68, 170, 16, 200, 66, 82, 86, 44, 68, 212, 184, 199, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 75, 252, 160, 69, 6, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0, 247, 239, 27, 68, 227, 16, 124, 64, 33, 229, 220, 67, 171, 9, 202, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 171, 9, 202, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 86, 90, 110, 69, 7, 11, 11, 2, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 91, 113, 167, 67, 92, 188, 60, 64, 223, 10, 42, 68, 58, 73, 206, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 58, 73, 206, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 214, 218, 146, 69, 18, 5, 19, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 235, 33, 44, 68, 26, 50, 118, 64, 22, 232, 74, 68, 64, 189, 200, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 189, 200, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 190, 18, 132, 69, 5, 6, 7, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 63, 156, 38, 68, 27, 127, 136, 64, 55, 132, 5, 68, 48, 100, 203, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 48, 100, 203, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 190, 116, 69, 35, 7, 16, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 214, 118, 54, 196, 239, 49, 70, 64, 111, 224, 185, 195, 176, 46, 202, 66, 200, 232, 13, 61, 176, 46, 202, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 229, 135, 68, 3, 7, 13, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 122, 220, 252, 67, 157, 82, 60, 64, 88, 205, 89, 68, 208, 106, 202, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 208, 106, 202, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 213, 35, 138, 69, 14, 11, 14, 2, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 43, 225, 15, 68, 97, 160, 103, 64, 244, 178, 187, 67, 216, 10, 202, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 216, 10, 202, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 42, 105, 69, 1, 8, 12, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 12, 73, 197, 67, 40, 119, 53, 64, 115, 141, 56, 68, 199, 157, 201, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 199, 157, 201, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 231, 143, 69, 10, 3, 8, 2, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 66, 178, 177, 67, 10, 45, 66, 64, 88, 176, 42, 68, 168, 124, 203, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 168, 124, 203, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 230, 9, 146, 69, 20, 3, 17, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 140, 235, 54, 68, 99, 244, 101, 64, 198, 155, 62, 68, 16, 171, 201, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 171, 201, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 109, 212, 129, 69, 33, 6, 9, 2, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 21, 102, 86, 66, 112, 68, 96, 64, 60, 2, 135, 65, 128, 194, 199, 66, 164, 206, 103, 66, 128, 194, 199, 66, 96, 174, 4, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 236, 0, 63, 69, 22, 0, 4, 3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 47, 20, 201, 67, 201, 159, 49, 64, 18, 130, 60, 68, 8, 44, 199, 66, 86, 200, 170, 66, 8, 44, 199, 66, 64, 16, 4, 66, 64, 253, 217, 65, 94, 90, 143, 69, 9, 4, 2, 3, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 32, 154, 227, 194, 27, 193, 93, 64, 243, 43, 77, 196, 251, 231, 201, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 251, 231, 201, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 112, 189, 255, 68, 23, 8, 10, 3, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 157, 12, 27, 66, 80, 210, 84, 64, 234, 220, 13, 68, 240, 20, 200, 66, 204, 189, 15, 67, 240, 20, 200, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 113, 36, 160, 69, 15, 4, 6, 2, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0, 70, 217, 139, 67, 81, 9, 51, 64, 70, 253, 57, 68, 81, 176, 206, 66, 204, 63, 149, 60, 81, 176, 206, 66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 71, 132, 149, 69, 31, 5, 20, 2, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 182, 135, 20, 192, 86, 227, 218, 187, 41, 207, 77, 187, 23, 39, 22, 59, 188, 55, 6, 59, 86, 40, 253, 58, 203, 2, 123, 66, 62, 192, 141, 194, 179, 242, 115, 66, 2, 233, 141, 194, 207, 30, 49, 191, 192, 105, 55, 62, 231, 125, 246, 190]
```

How would I be able to decode the data into a UDPPacket? In order to do this, I think I need to convert the data into four bytes and then somehow convert it to a float.

Here is my swift code:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftSocket

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var server: UDPServer!
    var timer: Timer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        server = UDPServer(address: "192.168.1.158", port: 20777)
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0, repeats: true) { _ in
            print("a")
            let data = self.server.recv(1289).0
            if let data = data {
                print(data)
                self.timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
        timer.fire()
    }
}
```

This is what the UDPPacket should look like:

```
struct UDPPacket

{

    float m_time;

    float m_lapTime;

    float m_lapDistance;

    float m_totalDistance;

    float m_x;  // World space position

    float m_y;  // World space position

    float m_z;  // World space position

    float m_speed;  // Speed of car in MPH

    float m_xv; // Velocity in world space

    float m_yv; // Velocity in world space

    float m_zv; // Velocity in world space

    float m_xr; // World space right direction

    float m_yr; // World space right direction

    float m_zr; // World space right direction

    float m_xd; // World space forward direction

    float m_yd; // World space forward direction

    float m_zd; // World space forward direction

    float m_susp_pos[4];    // Note: All wheel arrays have the order:

    float m_susp_vel[4];    // RL, RR, FL, FR

    float m_wheel_speed[4];

    float m_throttle;

    float m_steer;

    float m_brake;

    float m_clutch;

    float m_gear;

    float m_gforce_lat;

    float m_gforce_lon;

    float m_lap;

    float m_engineRate;

    float m_sli_pro_native_support; // SLI Pro support

    float m_car_position;   // car race position

    float m_kers_level; // kers energy left

    float m_kers_max_level; // kers maximum energy

    float m_drs;    // 0 = off, 1 = on

    float m_traction_control;   // 0 (off) - 2 (high)

    float m_anti_lock_brakes;   // 0 (off) - 1 (on)

    float m_fuel_in_tank;   // current fuel mass

    float m_fuel_capacity;  // fuel capacity

    float m_in_pits;    // 0 = none, 1 = pitting, 2 = in pit area

    float m_sector; // 0 = sector1, 1 = sector2, 2 = sector3

    float m_sector1_time;   // time of sector1 (or 0)

    float m_sector2_time;   // time of sector2 (or 0)

    float m_brakes_temp[4]; // brakes temperature (centigrade)

    float m_tyres_pressure[4];  // tyres pressure PSI

    float m_team_info;  // team ID 

    float m_total_laps; // total number of laps in this race

    float m_track_size; // track size meters

    float m_last_lap_time;  // last lap time

    float m_max_rpm;    // cars max RPM, at which point the rev limiter will kick in

    float m_idle_rpm;   // cars idle RPM

    float m_max_gears;  // maximum number of gears

    float m_sessionType;    // 0 = unknown, 1 = practice, 2 = qualifying, 3 = race

    float m_drsAllowed; // 0 = not allowed, 1 = allowed, -1 = invalid / unknown

    float m_track_number;   // -1 for unknown, 0-21 for tracks

    float m_vehicleFIAFlags;    // -1 = invalid/unknown, 0 = none, 1 = green, 2 = blue, 3 = yellow, 4 = red

    float m_era;                        // era, 2017 (modern) or 1980 (classic)

    float m_engine_temperature;     // engine temperature (centigrade)

    float m_gforce_vert;    // vertical g-force component

    float m_ang_vel_x;  // angular velocity x-component

    float m_ang_vel_y;  // angular velocity y-component

    float m_ang_vel_z;  // angular velocity z-component

    byte  m_tyres_temperature[4];   // tyres temperature (centigrade)

    byte  m_tyres_wear[4];  // tyre wear percentage

    byte  m_tyre_compound;  // compound of tyre – 0 = ultra soft, 1 = super soft, 2 = soft, 3 = medium, 4 = hard, 5 = inter, 6 = wet

    byte  m_front_brake_bias;         // front brake bias (percentage)

    byte  m_fuel_mix;                 // fuel mix - 0 = lean, 1 = standard, 2 = rich, 3 = max

    byte  m_currentLapInvalid;      // current lap invalid - 0 = valid, 1 = invalid

    byte  m_tyres_damage[4];    // tyre damage (percentage)

    byte  m_front_left_wing_damage; // front left wing damage (percentage)

    byte  m_front_right_wing_damage;    // front right wing damage (percentage)

    byte  m_rear_wing_damage;   // rear wing damage (percentage)

    byte  m_engine_damage;  // engine damage (percentage)

    byte  m_gear_box_damage;    // gear box damage (percentage)

    byte  m_exhaust_damage; // exhaust damage (percentage)

    byte  m_pit_limiter_status; // pit limiter status – 0 = off, 1 = on

    byte  m_pit_speed_limit;    // pit speed limit in mph

    float m_session_time_left;  // NEW: time left in session in seconds 

    byte  m_rev_lights_percent;  // NEW: rev lights indicator (percentage)

    byte  m_is_spectating;  // NEW: whether the player is spectating

    byte  m_spectator_car_index;  // NEW: index of the car being spectated



    // Car data

    byte  m_num_cars;               // number of cars in data

    byte  m_player_car_index;           // index of player's car in the array

    CarUDPData  m_car_data[20];   // data for all cars on track



    float m_yaw;  // NEW (v1.8)

    float m_pitch;  // NEW (v1.8)

    float m_roll;  // NEW (v1.8)

    float m_x_local_velocity;          // NEW (v1.8) Velocity in local space

    float m_y_local_velocity;          // NEW (v1.8) Velocity in local space

    float m_z_local_velocity;          // NEW (v1.8) Velocity in local space

    float m_susp_acceleration[4];   // NEW (v1.8) RL, RR, FL, FR

    float m_ang_acc_x;                 // NEW (v1.8) angular acceleration x-component

    float m_ang_acc_y;                 // NEW (v1.8) angular acceleration y-component

    float m_ang_acc_z;                 // NEW (v1.8) angular acceleration z-component


};
```

CarUDPData:

```
struct CarUDPData

{

    float m_worldPosition[3]; // world co-ordinates of vehicle

    float m_lastLapTime;

    float m_currentLapTime;

    float m_bestLapTime;

    float m_sector1Time;

    float m_sector2Time;

    float m_lapDistance;

    byte  m_driverId;

    byte  m_teamId;

    byte  m_carPosition;     // UPDATED: track positions of vehicle

    byte  m_currentLapNum;

    byte  m_tyreCompound;   // compound of tyre – 0 = ultra soft, 1 = super soft, 2 = soft, 3 = medium, 4 = hard, 5 = inter, 6 = wet

    byte  m_inPits;           // 0 = none, 1 = pitting, 2 = in pit area

    byte  m_sector;           // 0 = sector1, 1 = sector2, 2 = sector3

    byte  m_currentLapInvalid; // current lap invalid - 0 = valid, 1 = invalid

    byte  m_penalties;  // NEW: accumulated time penalties in seconds to be added

};
```

If it helps, I am at the start of a Grand Prix (not career), racing as Lewis Hamilton at Australia and the starting lights have not gone off yet.

Here is a link to the [UDP data specifications for F1 2017](http://forums.codemasters.com/discussion/53139/f1-2017-d-box-and-udp-output-specification/p1).

Comment: Hi! Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @Amit After a lot of research yes. Within the next week I may turn it into a framework for you and anyone else to download. I will then submit the answer. I'll see if I can get it to work with CocoaPods and Carthage depending on how easy it is to submit to them. Never submitted frameworks before.

Comment: Thanks @iProgram. Really appreciate it... Would love to help out if I can.